# Finding the density of a function of a distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I came across a question that defined the R.V $X$ to be uniformly distributed on the interval $[-2,1]$ and we are asked to find the density of $U=X^2$.

Since the function being applied to X is not injective, I opted for the method of distribution functions, thus: $$P(U\le u)$$ $$= P(X^2 \le u)$$ $$=P(-\sqrt{u} \le X \le \sqrt{u}) $$

It is clear by substitution that the bounds for $U$ are from $[0,4]$

So all that is left is to solve for: $$ \ \int_{-\sqrt{u}}^{\sqrt{u}} \frac{1}{3} \ dx \ $$ $$ = 2\frac{\sqrt{u}}{3} $$

This gives me my distribution function but after deriving to obtain the density: $$ f(u) = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{u}} $$ This does not give a valid density for the bounds $[0,4]$. I assume my error lies in the initial bounds for the derivation of the distribution function but after a little messing around I still cannot pinpoint where the mistake lies. And clues would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to split the domain of $F_U$ to several different regions and do calculations respectively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since the function being applied to X is not injective, I opted for the method of distribution functions, thus: $$P(U\le u)$$ $$= P(X^2 \le u)$$ $$=P(-\sqrt{u} \le X \le \sqrt{u}) $$

> It is clear by substitution that the bounds for $U$ are from $[0,4]$

Here is the mistake, if $U=4$, then you get $$P(-2 \le X \le 2) $$
But $X$ is between $[-2,1]$, hence can NEVER reach $2.$

So you need to split the bounds for $U$ as $[0,1]\cup [1,4]$

$U\in [0,1]$ corresponds to $X\in [-1,1]$

$U\in [1,4]$ corresponds to $X\in [-2,-1]$

Comment: So would this change be made in the initial solving for the distribution function? And if so how do I split up the region in terms of the sqrt(u) (since I need a function of u to be spit out)?

Comment: You initial calculation is only for the case $U\in [0, 1]$. So next, you need to re-do the calculation for the case $U\in [1,4]$. Think how to set the integration boundaries for $x$ in this case?

Comment: Okay perfect I see it now. So the bound -sqrtu to sqrt u would take into account the case from [-1,1] as you said, and clearly the bound -sqrtu to -1 (when u is between 1 and 4) would deal with the rest. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, that's correct!